# re-index button element value after removing table row with jquery

Tags: jquery

My problem is start when i remove the selected table row successfully but the button value in the last td on each table row is cannot update (reindex) with the javascript at the end. Please provide some solution on this.

```
<table id="sumTable" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Period</th>
<th>Discount</th>
<th>Remove</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="eachrow">
<td class="v-align-middle">test1@qwerty.com</td>
<td class="v-align-middle">Student</td>
<td class="v-align-middle">6 month</td>
<td class="v-align-middle">10%</td>
<td class="v-align-middle thisrow">
<button class="btn btn-small btn-link btn-del" value="0" name="subrow[]" type="button" sourceindex="2">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="eachrow">
<td class="v-align-middle">test2@qwerty.com</td>
<td class="v-align-middle">Student</td>
<td class="v-align-middle">6 month</td>
<td class="v-align-middle">10%</td>
<td class="v-align-middle thisrow">
<button class="btn btn-small btn-link btn-del" value="1" name="subrow[]" type="button" sourceindex="3">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="eachrow">
<td class="v-align-middle">test3@qwerty.com</td>
<td class="v-align-middle">Teacher</td>
<td class="v-align-middle">3 month</td>
<td class="v-align-middle">10%</td>
<td class="v-align-middle thisrow">
<button class="btn btn-small btn-link btn-del" value="2" name="subrow[]" type="button" sourceindex="4">
<i class="text-danger fa fa-times"></i>
</button>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

$('#sumTable').on('click', '.btn-del', function(e) {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    e.preventDefault();

    bootbox.confirm({
        title: '<?php echo translate('title_confirm_subdel'); ?>',
        message: '$<?php echo translate('text_confirm_subdel'); ?>',
        buttons: {
            'cancel': {
                label: '<?php echo translate('button_cancel'); ?>',
                className: 'btn-default'
            },
            'confirm': {
                label: '<?php echo translate('button_remove'); ?>',
                className: 'btn-danger'
            }
        },
        callback: function(result) {
            if (result) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'inc/token-recalc.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        'removeRow': rowData,
                        'tableData': $('#orderPoint').val()
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        var success = response.success;
                        var $orderDesc = response.orderDesc;
                        var $orderPoint = response.orderPoint;
                        var $orderAmount = response.orderAmount;
                        var $sumWell = response.sumWell;
                        if (success) {
                            $('#orderDesc').attr('value', $orderDesc);
                            $('#orderPoint').attr('value', $orderPoint);
                            $('#orderAmount').attr('value', $orderAmount);
                            $('#sumWell').html( $sumWell );
                        }
                    }
                });
                tr.fadeOut(400, function(){
                    tr.remove();
                });

                var sumTable = $('#sumTable > tbody > tr.eachrow');
                $(sumTable).each(function(i) {
                    $('td.thisrow', this).find('button').val(i);
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

this is the script that not working:

```
var sumTable = $('#sumTable > tbody > tr.eachrow');
$(sumTable).each(function(i) {
    $('td.thisrow', this).find('button').val(i);
});
```

Comment: The object `sumTable` is a jQuery object so it should be `sumTable.each(function(){})`

Comment: @Jackson i just tried, still not working but thanks on the quick response.

Comment: I'm not able to test anything now but have you tried putting the `tr.remove` outside of the `fadeout` block? I'm wondering if it isn't getting re-indexed because the row is still in the DOM when the re-ndexing is happening.

Comment: @John C You absolutely right! How can i accept this as Answer? I also embedded Jackson's code but without this nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment you are resetting the indexes, the element may still exist. Ending up in wrong reindexing. You can use the jquery `when` and `then` to solve this.

```
var resetNums = function(){
    $('#sumTable button').each(function(i) {
        $(this).html('button '+i);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sumTable').on('click', '.btn-del', function(e) {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        e.preventDefault();    
        tr.fadeOut(400, function(){
            $.when(tr.remove()).then(resetNums());
        });         
    });
    resetNums();
});
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/qt5e4jm9/2/

Comment: thank you for explaining this with details for me! i already embedded your suggestion and its works great!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is coming from the code within the `each()` function.

When you are iterating over each `tr.eachrow` element, you are losing the relational context by using `$(td.thisrow)`.

Instead try using this:

```
$('#sumTable tr.eachrow').each(function(i){
    $(this).find('button').val(i);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your buttons are not being re-indexed because the row that's being removed  is still in the DOM when the re-indexing happens. Try doing your re-indexing in your `fadeout` complete function -

```
tr.fadeOut(400, function(){
  tr.remove();
  var sumTable = $('#sumTable > tbody > tr.eachrow');
    sumTable.each(function(i) {
      $('td.thisrow', this).find('button').val(i);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I accepted Sam's answer, its a complete solution that keep the fadeOut as well. Thank you again! Voted up!